# Issue saving NSDictionary values to core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary

NOTE: Please fully read the problem before devoting it or closing it.

I have a dictionary `packedData` which has a value '1' in it of `NSNumber` type & of key "example". I save this value to core data as

```
myentity.attribute = [packedData valueForKey:@"example"];  //attribute is of NSNumber type as well.
```

when I fetch the data, the value returned is "23008" or some other unrelated value. I debugged it to find that it's a value conversion issue while saving it to core data.

Does anyone know why this occurs or its solution??

UPDATE: NSString and NSDate type are saved fine (exact values as in dictionary).

Comment: @pbasdf that was just used for exemplary purpose. Edited the key name for better understanding

Comment: What is the type you're using to store `attribute` in Core Data?

Comment: Is `myentity.attribute` ok after the assignment?

Comment: @Willeke if you mean that it causes no error, then yes it doesn't.  No exceptions either.

Comment: @bbarnhart Attribute is of Int16

Comment: How are you checking the returned value? What values do you get? You mention 23008, what else?

Comment: Is the value of `myentity.attribute` `1` after `myentity.attribute = [packedData valueForKey:@"example"];`? Any problems with other attributes of the same object? Where in the saving process is the value conversion issue, when is the value correct and when is it something else?

Comment: @Willeke I debugged that exact single line with a checkpoint (on the line below this one to ensure line execution before analysis). In the console I wrote 'po [packedData valueForKey:@"example")' and it showed 1. When I wrote 'po myentity' it showed a weird value for attribute. Only attributes of NSNumber type (storage type Int16/64) are behaving like this. String type attributes are saved fine

Comment: @Tom the returned value is always some random value. (I have suspicions that it's the default value of the attribute, NOT SURE THOUGH). And about checking the returned value, read my above comment.

Comment: In your data model, does "attribute" have "Use Scalar Type" checked?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes it does

Comment: @TomHarrington I tried unchecking "use scalar property" and it worked! I don't understand the property's effect though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "use scalar property" selected for an integer type property, the generated code is something like

```
@property (nonatomic) int16_t attribute;
```

If you uncheck that, the code looks like

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *attribute;
```

The first case is a raw integer type; the second one is an `NSNumber` object that Core Data will treat as containing an integer.

Your line of code looks like this:

```
myentity.attribute = [packedData valueForKey:@"example"];
```

The `valueForKey` call will return an object, in your case an `NSNumber`. But there's no automatic conversion between `NSNumber` and scalar types. So if you're using the scalar version you end up assigning the pointer value of the `NSNumber`. That is, you get the memory address of the `NSNumber` instead of the value it contains.

You can fix this either by

- Not using the scalar type, so that you have an `NSNumber` everywhere.
- Keeping the scalar type but then changing your line of code to convert the object to its integer value:

  ```
  newEvent.attribute = [[packedData valueForKey:@"example"] integerValue];
  ```

The compiler should have warned you about this! I would have expected a warning reading something like `incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int16_t' (aka 'short') from 'id _Nullable'`.

Comment: Compiler did issue said warning and I had already tried resolving it by exactly as in your second suggestion. But it gave me the following error " Implicit conversion of 'long _Nullable' to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC".

Comment: That error indicates that `attribute` was an object in that case, but that you were assigning a scalar integer value to it. Either approach is OK as long as your usage is consistent.